# How to do Count validation for realtime streaming data

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, hbase

I am working in a project ,where the architecture is like below:

Transactions initiated from web application first get stored in oracle DB(Transactional database) and after that it will ingested into Bigdata framework and get processed and then stored in Hbase. CR8 is used to real timedata integration, it captures all the transactional logs from oracle and send to kafka .After that spark jobs processed these data in real time  and store the processed data in Hbase

To make sure all the transaction records in oracle DB are received in Hbase what I am doing is taking  Sample of 1000 transactionIDs from Oracle and checking the 1000 IDs are present in Hbase or not. I can only do count validation on  sample records.

Is there any method to do 100% countvalidation,to ensure whatever the transaction record in Oracle is ingested into Hbase or not.

Am expecting something like -validate argument in  SQOOP import job which  doing the 100 % count validation between RDBMS and HDFS.

Or is there any other way to do count validation in the above architecture?